# File upload with path (CSS)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Example:

[image: Example]

I'm just starting to learn jQuery and I want to make something similar to this upload field, but I don't know how exactly it can be done. Maybe someone can help. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried to google ? E.G. "how to add css style on file upload button" - first result is: http://geniuscarrier.com/how-to-style-a-html-file-upload-button-in-pure-css/ . Always first deeply google before posting question as almost 95% of all your questions already have answer somewhere in the web

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
  StackOverflow is not a coding or tutorial service.